# Expand animation of a row in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have a `ListView` with restaurants. Each row has an expand button which lets you see the restaurant's menu. I'm trying to add a smooth expand animation. So far I've got something like this:

```
TranslateAnimation expandAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, -targetHeight, 0f)
expandAnimation.setDuration(300)
menuLayout.startAnimation(expandAnimation)
```

It is smooother than actually changing height with something like `ValueAnimator` (which is what I tried before).

My problem is that this animates only the row whose menu is expanding. I would like to animate also the visible rows below the row with expanding menu to achieve better visual effect. I tried to get them from the `ListView` with `ListView.getChildAt()` and apply similar `TranslateAnimation` on them but this doesn't work if the menu is too long. I believe this happens due to the `View` being recycled by my `ListView` so is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this Library, as per your explanation this will work perfectly
https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like exatcly what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy coding buddy 